# Unexpected value error using fill_between function of matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I've written a straight-forward code that plots two lines. Then I try to fill the region between them using fill_between but I get this weird error that I don't understand:

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_axes.py", line 5101, in fill_between
> 'is not 1-dimensional.')
> ValueError: Input passed into argument "u'x'"is not 1-dimensional.

Here is my code sample, where q, DelTheta5, DelTheta50, DelTheta95 are each np arrays of the same dimension and size,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.figure(1)
#fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(q, DelTheta5, linewidth=2, linestyle='dashed', color='black')
plt.plot(q ,DelTheta50, linewidth=2, color='black')
plt.plot(q, DelTheta95, linewidth=2, linestyle='dotted', color='black')
plt.fill_between(q, DelTheta5, DelTheta95)
```

I can get it to work with a different example I found online that uses random data. But it doesn't work for me with the data and code snippet above (the syntax looks correct to me). Does anybody know the source of this ValueError? My data arrays are clean (all elements are floats). I'm using python 2.7.18.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The are no issues with the syntax. Can you reproduce it with a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that you can share with us?

Comment: Also, did you check the arrays shapes, and squeeze any singleton dimensions with `np.squeeze`?

Comment: It looks like the np.squeeze did the trick!! My arrays were being imported from a .mat file, so there must have been some extra dimension hanging around. I had been trying a few ways of re-sizing the arrays but they didn't work. This np.squeeze functions works though! Thank you so much! If you write your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Leonard's comment was exactly correct. I needed to use np.squeeze since there was an extra dimension in my data arrays: i.e. they were column vectors [] but had an extra ([]) around them.